# Update field of a table if joining table has 2 or more columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have 2 tables named `Order` and `OrderDetail`

Order table contains

```
OrderID --  DetailCount
  1 ------------Multiple
  2 ------------
```

Order detail contains

```
OrderID ------ Description
1 ------------------ Test1
1 ------------------ Test1
2 ------------------ Test1
```

How to join the above 2 tables in order to update `Order` table's `DetailCount` by counting the records in `OrderDetail` table.
If `OrderDetail` has more the 1 column by joining the `OrderID`, `DetailCount` value should be 'Multiple'.

I came up with the below query. But contains an error. How can I solve this?

```
UPDATE o
SET o.DetailCount = 'Multiple'
FROM #Order o
INNER JOIN #OrderDetail od
ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
WHERE COUNT(od.OrderID) > 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE o
  SET DetailCount = 'Multiple'
FROM #Order o
WHERE o.OrderID IN (SELECT od.OrderID
                    FROM #OrderDetail od
                    GROUP BY od.OrderID
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                   );
```

Although you can phrase this using a `JOIN`, I just think that filtering in the `WHERE` clause is more in the spirit of an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
UPDATE o
      SET o.DetailCount = (CASE WHEN od.od_cnt > 1 
                                THEN 'Multple' 
                                ELSE CAST(od.od_cnt AS VARCHAR(255)) 
                            END)
FROM #Order o CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS od_cnt
       FROM #OrderDetail od
       WHERE od.OrderID = o.OrderID
     ) od;
```

If you want to update the `OrderID` which has only more then one count then include `where` clause & remove `case` expression :

```
UPDATE o
      SET o.DetailCount = 'Multple' 
FROM #Order o CROSS APPLY
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS od_cnt
       FROM #OrderDetail od
       WHERE od.OrderID = o.OrderID
     ) od
WHERE od.od_cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this alternative using HAVING

```
UPDATE o
  SET o.DetailCount = 'Multiple'
FROM #Order o
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT OrderID
    FROM #OrderDetail
    GROUP BY OrderID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) x 
ON o.OrderID = x.OrderID
```